# Curve text with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, annotations

I am trying to add the curve text in my graph. Any help on how to get it like the pic below?

[image: Original graph]

This is what I got:

[image: My graph]

```r
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolo89/Raw_Data/main/Hurricane.csv")
hurricane <- read.csv(text = x)

graph1 <-  ggplot(hurricane, aes(year, average, color = type)) +
    geom_step(size=.8) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1860,2020,20)) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(0,8.5),
        breaks = seq(2,8,2),
        expand = c(0,0)
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#735ad2", "#3b2d74")) +  
    labs(
        y = " ",
        x = " ", 
        title = "15-year average recorded Atlantic basin hurricanes, 1851-2019"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() 
graph1
```

Comment: You want `geomtextpath`: https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worked example using `geomtextpath`:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

x <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolo89/Raw_Data/main/Hurricane.csv"
hurricane <- read.csv(x)

ggplot(hurricane, aes(year, average, color = type)) +
  geom_step(size=.8) +
  geom_textline(aes(label = ifelse(type == "avg_h_15year", 
                    "All Hurricanes",
                    "Major Hurricanes"), y = average + 1.2), 
                text_smoothing = 50, fontface = 2,
                hjust = 0,  linetype = 0, size = 7) +
  annotate("text", x = 1900, y = 2.5, label = "Category 3 - 5", hjust = 0,
           color = "#3b2d74") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1860,2020,20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0,8.5),
    breaks = seq(2,8,2),
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#735ad2", "#3b2d74"), guide = "none") +  
  labs(
    y = " ",
    x = " ", 
    title = "15-year average recorded Atlantic basin hurricanes, 1851-2019"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]